# TimeOut Error when trying to use COBLogin()

Tags: yodlee

I'm getting a timeout error when I try to call COBLogin with the new private REST URL, username and password I received from our sales rep. When I use my developer portal REST url, username and password the code works fine.

Is there any sort of permissioning that I need to bring up with my sales rep?

Update: Yodlee customer support got back to me. The IP address which calls the function has to be on a list that we had provided earlier for security. Setup a VPN and reran the code and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Great. For any customer issue we have our dedicated customer support team to help you out.

To be helpful for other Yodlee API users- Once you get your private credentials your IPs has to be whitelisted, though we are in process of skipping this step as per our customer's requests. Albeit public zone still needs IP whitelisting.